# MYSQl Query with union is failing

Tags: mysql, union

I have a two tables A and B
I would like to union them and store in to another table;

```
CREATE TABLE  myspace.test (
(select * from A ) UNION ( select * from B) );
```

It fails with an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE
>   myspace.test ( (select * from A )
>   UNION ( s' at line 1

But the query with: `(select * from A ) UNION ( select * from B)` gives correct result.

How to store union result in to another table??

Thanks Arman.

**EDIT**

Well After playing around I found that:

- The query without outer brackets works.

  CREATE TABLE  myspace.test 
  (select * from A ) UNION ( select * from B) ;
- Adding **AS** is not solving the problem.
- I was wondered that query with brackets is working well seems tome BUG or maybe I am missing something?

  CREATE TABLE  myspace.test 
  (select * from A);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html). There are no parens around the `select-statement`.

```
CREATE TABLE `myspace`.`test` (SELECT * FROM `A`) UNION (SELECT * FROM `B`);
```

Watch out for duplicate primary keys, though. You may want to consider first creating an empty table `myspace.test` with the proper layout, then inserting rows into it more selectively.

Comment: Nice, but why `CREATE TABLE `myspace`.`test` (SELECT * FROM `A`)` statement works?

Comment: @Arman: Not sure offhand. Look through the grammar in the documentation.

Comment: Does anyone figure out the difference? I have always create table using parentheses for aesthetic purpose. Somehow using `UNION` in the create table makes a difference. Very puzzling.

Comment: @Heisenberg: It's not that puzzling, and it doesn't really matter. It's just how it is.

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE
        myspace.test
AS
SELECT  *
FROM    A
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    B
```

Comment: Nice solution. This will really work if there is no auto-increment ID defined in tables A and B. If there is then it'll most likely have duplicates.

Comment: @Skorpioh: @op states that his query returns correct results (whatever his means by that). All I did was a little syntax correction.

Comment: The AS was not a issue the outer brackets are not allowed when I do union.I just added Edit.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look right at first sight.

Start by simply creating your new empty table using CREATE TABLE.

Then run a query to populate it, should be something like

```
INSERT INTO newTable(field1, field2,..., fieldN)
SELECT temp.field1, temp.field2,...,temp.fieldN
FROM
(
    SELECT field1, field2,...,fieldN
    FROM A
    UNION
    SELECT field1, field2,...,fieldN
    FROM B
) temp
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Scorpioh:Thanks, but unfortunately I cannot create newTable because the layout of results are unknown.